# Input type changes automatically inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I have paid attention to very strange problem while using Fluent Validation `Must` clause.

Let's say I have such model:

```
public class PhoneDetail
{
    public int PrefixId { get; set; }
    public string Digits { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the validator:

```
public PhoneDetailValidator()
{
    this.RuleFor(phone => phone.Digits)
        .Must(x => x == null);
}
```

***What is the type of*** `x` ***in your opinion***? `String`? Yes, you are right.

[image]

***But, then what is this?***

[image]

*It has changed it's type from* `string` *to* `PhoneDetail`.
I am using ***Visual Studio 2012***.

Is that bug or something?

**Update:**

Also, it worth to say that in first case it is compiling just fine. But, in the second case compiler error is occuring:

```
> Delegate 'System.Func<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.PhoneDetail,string,bool>'
> does not take 1 arguments
```

Comment: It just shows the name of the containing instance type (`PhoneDetails`).

Comment: Looks like an IDE bug to me. In fact I've just tried the same code and it's showing me `string`.

Comment: @DavidG May be, I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I don't have 2012 to test with, but I susepct if you close IDE and re-open it will be OK.

Comment: @DavidG I have closed an reopened it. Still same. Also, we have tested this in my friend's pc also. Same result.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev http://i.imgur.com/CU6WhLp.png

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev And does it compile if you use `x.Digits`?

Comment: @DavidG Updated my question. Compiler error is occuring in secon case.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev That error should only be one of them, I would guess you also have one saying `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Digits' and no extension method 'Digits' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found`?

Comment: @DavidG Not, I have updated my qeustion with message. `Delegate 'System.Func<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.PhoneDetail,string,bool>'
    > does not take 1 arguments`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's either an IDE bug or it's trying to be clever by showing you the IntelliSense for another overload of the `Must` method. One of the other overloads takes a slightly different `Func` which includes the root object, so you can write:

```
this.RuleFor(phone => phone.Digits)
            .Must((phone, x) => phone.Digits == null);
```

Comment: You could probably write `.Must((string x) => x == null))` too.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie You could but it's a little redundant and doesn't use the second overload.

Comment: True, but in the same sense, you're not using the second parameter of your lambda. They're both messy, but I feel the advantage of the `(string x)` approach is that it doesn't change the compiled code.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Yes, but OP isn't having a problem compiling `x => x == null`, it's just the IDE that is showing something odd.

Comment: I agree - but if all we're doing is working around an IDE rendering issue, then I'd prefer to avoid changes which alter the compiled code.